# How to make a unit do x then y in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

In a replay against a Protoss I saw that they were making their units do one task, x, then another task, y, right away without waiting for task x to finish before telling the unit to do task y. So I would they would in a moment setup a line for the unit to task x (build a pylon) then task y (build another pylon).

How do I do this?

Comment: This is frequently known as queueing, or waypoints.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while issuing orders to the unit

Comment: As a small addendum: Some players are confused when they do a shift-command after an attack-move command (such as attack-move, followed by a storm or something).  If you encounter the enemy forces your units will fight and keep fighting until the "attack-move" is done, before executing the spell or what-not.

Comment: Also, you can queue special abilities. With siege tanks you can tell them to move to a location and then set up in siege mode.  Works the same with vikings, burrowing zerg units, warp prisms and etc.  Also special abilities like psionic storm, emp, etc.  Practice with the siege tanks, though.  If they are in siege mode and you give them the un-siege command, there is a slight pause before you can queue more actions.  But is possible to queue up: un-siege, move and siege up again

Answer (score 0):

Protoss Probes can initiate a building "teleport" and continue doing whatever it was doing without having to wait for the building to finish "teleporting" (*)

That means that a Probe and start building a new structure and go back to gather ressources (or start to build another structure)

Terrans SCV will actually build the structure and Zerg Drones will metamorphose.

Comment: Ugh. It's called "warping in". It's clearly written on EVERY structure production and unit production popup.