# How to route units in sc2?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a unit do x then y in Starcraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5388/how-to-make-a-unit-do-x-then-y-in-starcraft-2)

I have seen people using their marines to scout terrirotty based on a predefined route.

Go to A, go to B, return to A, got o C etc

From what i understand it is done through a series of clicks. But how?

Comment: I thought this had already been asked, but I can't find it.

Comment: @McKay me either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Holding <kbd>shift</kbd> while issuing an action queues the action to be done after the unit has done the actions that it has already been told to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the shift key to queue up waypoints (or actions, such as attack, cast spell, build, etc).